# Will Keyword NEW reinitialize all others running function value in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, oop

I have a Class file to perform certain function , for example

```
public class clsFunction
{
   public DataTable FunctionOne()
   {
      //some code
   }

   public void FunctionTwo()
   {
     //Some Code
   }
}
```

SecondClass is use to call function from clsFunction , and this main class in running on a console program with multiple thread.

```
public class SecondClass 
{
   public void ThreadOne()
   {
      while(true){DataTable dt = new clsFunction().FunctionOne;}
   }
   public void ThreadTwo()
   {
      while(true){new clsFunction().FunctionTwo();}
   }
}

class Main
{
   static void Main (string[] args)
   {
     //Thread to start SecondClass.ThreadOne
     //THread to start SecondClass.ThreadTwo
   }
}
```

My concern is will my class value reinitialize to default value when I call `new clsFunction()` each time. for example , thread two may running it own value , when thread one is call , will all the thread two value change to it default value ?

Comment: Do you have any static variables you're re-initializing in `FunctionOne` or `FunctionTwo`?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov I dont have any static variable in it

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you don't understand what new does. It creates an object. It's purpose is not to initialize something that already exists. Objects are independent.

Creating an object has no influence on any other object, except of course if the constructor does something to influence other objects.

Comment: When you have a global static variable that you mutate between instances, that could change.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you make the ctor write to other instances or static state all bets are off.

Comment: I mean that when you have a static variable that is mutated in `FunctionOne` or `FunctionTwo`, this cancels the "Objects are independent" statement.

Comment: I don't think so because the object are independent. Writing to one of them does not change the other. I'm not interested in discussing the situation that one of the methods involved here mutates other objects or statics. In that case clearly anything at all is possible.

Comment: *I'm not interested in discussing the situation* But that OP might have such a case. When you say *Creating an object has no influence on any other object*, you have to add a disclaimer to when *it isn't* the case as well.

Comment: I think I did add that ("except of course if the constructor does something to influence other objects."). If other methods mutate state that has nothing to do with object creation so I'm safe here as well. I should be a lawyer.

Comment: LOL. It isn't only up to the constructor to mutate "other objects". It could be that the method is updating a static variable read by all instances, in which would effect all instances. Anyway, you get my point.